# Packing for distribution with CodeKit 2

Tags: codekit

I'm playing around with CodeKit 2 but I haven't figure out how to make a **dist** the way you do it with grunt or gulp, putting everything in a dist/ folder because now the compressed and minified files are mixed with the rest. Also, the `.html` have things like `<script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>`.

Again, I just want to get rid of the `bower_components` in my final html and not having to move manually the final css and js to a different place.

I hope don't have to do it manually, lol. Anyhelp? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Grunt, in CodeKit 2 you have to do this manually. It is not hard, just a matter of drag and drop. Select your `js/app.js` and open the `bower_components` folder and drag the files you want to **combine/minified** to the imports tab in CodeKit. This is the video for more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZagUmzSbYI